# Connect AWS Red Shift with Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, database-connection

I  want to connect my rails(6) project with AWS RedShift.
I have tried these  [DOC1](https://github.com/tuesy/redshift-ruby-tutorial), [DOC2](https://github.com/iamdbc/activerecord6-redshift-adapter) but getting the same error.

Error is "PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection timed out.
Is the server running on host "...us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com" (IP) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5439?"

Database configuration:

```
development:  
  adapter: redshift
  host: '....us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com'
  port: 5439
  database: 'DB Name'
  username: 'Root User Name'
  password: 'DB Password'
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 3
  timeout: 5000
```

Red Shift cluster Security group inbound rules:

```
  Type          RedShfit
  Protocol      TCP
  Port          5439
  Destination   127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Where is your Rails project running? Is it on an Amazon EC2 instance or your own computer? If your own computer, is the what is the Redshift setting for `Publicly Accessible`? Also, please Edit your Question to show the configuration of the Security Group attached to the Amazon Redshift database.

Comment: Rails Project is running on local and Cluster is VPC.

Comment: Inbound rules have a Source, not a Destination. Please double-check.

Answer (score 0):

If your local computer on the Internet wants to connect to Redshift, then the following will need to be configured:

- Redshift cluster is in a Public Subnet
- Redshift cluster is configured as `Publicly Accessible = Yes`
- The Security Group associated with the Redshift cluster has a rule that permits Inbound access on port 5439 **from your own public IP address**